# Python - Encoding issues while reading an SQL Server table with Pandas and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyarrow

I'm having a problem with the encoding for some reason that I can't figure it out.

```
`for tbl in table:
                
                df = pd.read_sql_table(f'{tbl[0]}', mssql_engine())
                filename = (tbl[0]+'.parquet')
                path = (tmppath+filename)

                df.to_parquet(path, compression=None)`
```

So far it was going well, until it appeared the following error in one of the tables:

> 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 46-47: illegal UTF-16 surrogate

I tried changing the charset when using `create_engine` :

```
def mssql_engine(user=sqluser, password=sqlpassword, host=sqlserver, db=sqldatabase):
    engine = create_engine(
        f'mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{password}@{host}/{db}?driver=SQL+Server&charset=latin1')
    return engine
```

But the same error persists. I tried looking if there was any strange characters in the table but I didn't find any.

EDIT: I did inspect on the table columns and this is the result of one of the columns:

> {'name': 'Column', 'type': VARCHAR(length=2, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI'), 'nullable': True, 'default': None, 'autoincrement': False},

Comment: Which statement is failing?

Comment: @GordThompson The pd.read_sql_table statement

Comment: For the table that is failing, [edit] your question to include the results from `insp = sa.inspect(engine); print(insp.get_columns("table_name"))` (assuming `import sqlalchemy as sa`)

Comment: @GordThompson I included one of the columns

Comment: Well, that column is probably not the culprit as it is not likely to return ~48 bytes (more like 2, or maybe 4, bytes). What I would do is: Verify that the error occurs with `read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name"`. Then narrow down the column that is causing the failure using a good old binary search. (Try with the first half of the columns and the last half of the columns. Whichever fails, divide that set of columns in half and try again. Repeat until the offending column is identified.)